# Using Python to create a JSON file of recipes from MySQL

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, mysql, json

I needed to create a JSON file from a couple of MySQL tables to migrate some recipes from wordpress.
This was my first time writing a script in python and would like to get some feedback on what I could have done better. I come from a Javascript background.

```
import mysql.connector
import json

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
    database='somedb', user='root', password='root', host='localhost'
)

cnx1 = mysql.connector.connect(
    database='somedb', user='root', password='root', host='localhost'
)

cursor = cnx.cursor();
cursor1 = cnx1.cursor();

query = "SELECT a.recipe_id, a.recipe_item_type, b.meta_key, b.meta_value, b.recipe_item_id FROM wp_simmer_recipe_items a, wp_simmer_recipe_itemmeta b WHERE a.recipe_item_id = b.recipe_item_id GROUP BY a.recipe_item_id"
query1 = "SELECT * FROM wp_simmer_recipe_itemmeta WHERE recipe_item_id=(%s)"

cursor.execute(query)
rs = cursor.fetchall()

data = {}

for row in rs:
    if row[1] == 'instruction':
        cursor1.execute(query1, (row[4],))
        insD = cursor1.fetchall()
        for instruction in insD:
            if instruction[2] != 'is_heading':
                data.setdefault(row[0], {'instructions':[], 'ingredients': []})['instructions'].append(instruction[3]);
    else:
        cursor1.execute(query1, (row[4],))
        rd = cursor1.fetchall()
        ingredient = {}
        for itemMeta in rd:
            ingredient[itemMeta[2]] = itemMeta[3]
        data.setdefault(row[0], {'ingredients': [], 'instructions': []})['ingredients'].append(ingredient)


with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

cursor1.close()
cnx1.close()
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

### Preface

For this review, we shall need to refer to the [database schema for the WordPress Simmer plugin](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/simmer/tags/1.3.11/core/class-simmer-installer.php#L176):

> ```
> if ( $items_table_name != $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$items_table_name'" ) ) {
>         // The recipe items table.
>         $query .= "CREATE TABLE $items_table_name (
>                recipe_item_id bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
>                recipe_item_type varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>                recipe_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
>                recipe_item_order int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>                PRIMARY KEY  (recipe_item_id),
>                KEY recipe_id (recipe_id)
>                ) $charset_collate;";
> }
>
> if ( $item_meta_table_name != $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$item_meta_table_name'" ) ) {
>
>         // The recipe item meta table.
>         $query .= "CREATE TABLE $item_meta_table_name (
>                meta_id bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
>                recipe_item_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
>                meta_key varchar(255) NULL,
>                meta_value longtext NULL,
>                PRIMARY KEY  (meta_id),
>                KEY recipe_item_id (recipe_item_id),
>                KEY meta_key (meta_key)
>                ) $charset_collate;";
> }
> ```

### Querying

To start, let's format your first `query` for readability:

```
query = """
    SELECT a.recipe_id, a.recipe_item_type
         , b.meta_key, b.meta_value, b.recipe_item_id
        FROM wp_simmer_recipe_items a, wp_simmer_recipe_itemmeta b
        WHERE a.recipe_item_id = b.recipe_item_id
        GROUP BY a.recipe_item_id
"""
```

Your `query` has a **non-sensical `GROUP BY` clause**.  The only way that this query could be legal is if the schema and query are formulated so as to guarantee that each `recipe_item_id` only appears at most once in the query result.  While the `wp_simmer_recipe_items` table does have a `PRIMARY KEY (recipe_item_id)` constraint, there is no such uniqueness guarantee in the `wp_simmer_recipe_itemmeta` table.  MySQL < 5.7.5 somehow executes the query despite the fact that it makes no sense; [in MySQL ≥ 5.7.5, it should fail with an error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html), as it should in any sane SQL implementation:

> ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'somedb.b.meta_key' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Based on the query results, you build the `ingredients` and `instructions` lists by appending entries.  However, you fail to `ORDER BY recipe_item_order`, so the **ingredients and instructions may appear in any order**.  (Try baking the bread before mixing the dough!)

When joining tables, write the query using `JOIN`. It's more readable than implicitly joining tables using the `WHERE` clause.

The worst sin in this code is **executing `query1` for each recipe found by `query`**.  This is a bad idea for two reasons:

- For good performance, you should **never execute queries in a loop**, especially when the number of secondary queries depends on the length of the results of the primary query.  Each additional query necessitates a round trip to the server, and takes time to interpret and execute.
- The information returned by **`query1` is entirely redundant** — all of the information you need from it (namely, the `meta_key` and `meta_value` for each `recipe_item_id`) is already contained within the results of `query`!

Furthermore, you don't need to make **two connections to the same database**.  All you need is two cursors, which can be created from just one connection.

### Suggested solution

Execute two queries: one to get the instructions, one to get the ingredients. (Here, I've taken a shortcut and assumed that every recipe will have at least one instruction and at least one ingredient.)

Take advantage of [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to help construct the inner lists and dictionaries.

```
from itertools import groupby
import json
from operator import itemgetter
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
    database='somedb', user='root', password='root', host='localhost'
)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
data = {}

cursor.execute("""
    SELECT item.recipe_id
         , meta.meta_value AS instruction_text
        FROM wp_simmer_recipe_items item
            INNER JOIN wp_simmer_recipe_itemmeta meta
                ON item.recipe_item_id = meta.recipe_item_id
        WHERE
            item.recipe_item_type = 'instruction'
            AND meta.meta_key <> 'is_heading'
        ORDER BY item.recipe_id, item.recipe_item_order
""")
for recipe_id, instructions in groupby(cursor.fetchall(), itemgetter(0)):
    data[recipe_id] = {
        'instructions': [row[1] for row in instructions],
        'ingredients': [],
    }

cursor.execute("""
    SELECT item.recipe_id
         , meta.recipe_item_id
         , meta.meta_key
         , meta.meta_value
        FROM wp_simmer_recipe_items item
            INNER JOIN wp_simmer_recipe_itemmeta meta
                ON item.recipe_item_id = meta.recipe_item_id
        WHERE
            item.recipe_item_type <> 'instruction'
        ORDER BY item.recipe_id, item.recipe_item_order, meta.meta_key
""")
for (recipe_id, item_id), item in groupby(cursor.fetchall(), itemgetter(0, 1)):
    data[recipe_id]['ingredients'].append({row[2]: row[3] for row in item})

cursor.close()
cnx.close()

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

### Further discussion

MySQL, since version 5.7.22, has JSON support.  It would be nice to rewrite the SQL such that the entire JSON result could be returned from just a single query.  Unfortunately, the [`JSON_ARRAYAGG()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) does not let you specify the order of its results:

> `JSON_ARRAYAGG(col_or_expr)`
>
> Aggregates a result set as a single JSON array whose elements consist of the rows. *The order of elements in this array is undefined.*

That, to me, would be a deal-breaker for exporting a recipe.

Comment: It would be nice to also give clear names for `row[2]: row[3] for row in item_attributes`, instead of indexing `row`.

Comment: @Graipher You could use [`cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursordict.html) for better readability (presumably with a negligible performance impact).

Answer (score 1):

## Object-relational mapping

Consider using an ORM framework, such like [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html) or [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/).
it will significally enhance code readability and reusability.

With `peewee`:

```
class WpSimmerRecipeItems(Model):

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'wp_simmer_recipe_items'

    recipe_id = AutoField()
    …


class WpSimmerRecipeItemMeta(Mode):

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'wp_simmer_recipe_itemmeta'

    …
```

The respective select query:

```
selection = WpSimmerRecipeItems.select(
    WpSimmerRecipeItems.recipe_id,
    WpSimmerRecipeItems.recipe_item_type,
    WpSimmerRecipeItemMeta.meta_key,
    WpSimmerRecipeItemMeta.meta_value,
    WpSimmerRecipeItemMeta.recipe_item_id).join(
        WpSimmerRecipeItemMeta,
        on=(WpSimmerRecipeItems.recipe_item_id == WpSimmerRecipeItemMeta.recipe_item_id).group_by(
            WpSimmerRecipeItems.recipe_item_id)
```

Unfortunately I cannot go into too much detail here, since I don't know your database's structure.

In the case of `peewee` this would also make the JSON conversion trivial using `playhouse.shortcuts.model_to_dict`:

```
json_list = [model_to_dict(record) for record in selection]
```

Comment: Perhaps a better ORM would be the WordPress Simmer plugin itself, in which case the JSON exporter should be written in PHP.